# Replace the last occurence of a string (and only it) using regular expression

Tags: r, regex

I have a string, let say MyString = "aabbccawww". I would like to use a gsub expression to replace the last "a" in MyString by "A", **and only it**. That is "aabbccAwww". I have found similar questions on the website, but they all requested to replace the last occurrence and everything coming after.
I have tried gsub("a[^a]*$", "A", MyString), but it gives "aabbccA". I know that I can use stringi functions for that purpose but I need the solution to be implemented in a part of a code where using such functions would be complicated, so I would like to use a regular expression.
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 13):

You can use `stringi` library which makes dealing with strings very easy, i.e.

```
library(stringi)

x <- "aabbccawww"
stri_replace_last_fixed(x, 'a', 'A')
#[1] "aabbccAwww"
```

Answer (score 12):

We can use `sub` to match 'a' followed by zero or more characters that are not an 'a' (`[^a]*`), capture it as group (`(...)`) until the end of the string (`$`) and replace it with "A" followed by the backreference of the captured group (`\\1`)

```
sub("a([^a]*)$", "A\\1", MyString)
#[1] "aabbccAwww"
```

Comment: Thanks. do you have a suggestion not using "A\\1" but an empty raplacement? So just a regular expression that would tell: the last "a" in the string.

Answer (score 4):

While akrun's answer should solve the problem (not sure, haven't worked with `\1` etc. yet), you can also use lookouts:

```
a(?!(.|\n)*a)
```

This is basically saying: Find an `a` that is NOT followed by any number of characters and an `a`. The `(?!x)` is a so-called lookout, which means that the searched expression won't be included in the match.

You need `(.|\n)` since `.` refers to all characters, except for line breaks.

For reference about lookouts or other regex, I can recommend http://regexr.com/.

Comment: I tried: gsub("a(?!(.|\n)*a)" ,"A", MyString). It does not work "invalid regexp". Do you have any idea?

Comment: Could be that regex in R doesn't support lookouts, I'm not a R developer - I just tried to give a general solution. Anyhow, if it doesn't support lookouts, just dump my solution, it won't be of any help in that case. Another idea, although I don't know if that's possible in R: can you iterate over your string backwards? If so, you could replace the first found `a` (which equals the last `a` in the string, seeing as you're going backwards) and get the desired result.

Comment: You can set the flag `perl = TRUE` to use perl-comptaible regex in R (e.g. `sub("a(?!(.|\n)*a)", "", MyString, perl = TRUE)`