# how to remove a specific forward slash in a URL?

Tags: r, regex

Consider this simple example `url`

```
http://this-is-a-nice-example/2020.htm
```

I am trying to write a regex that replaces the last `/` with an empty space, so that the `url` actually reads `http://this-is-a-nice-example2020.htm`

Unfortunately, the regex below returns a surprising result

```
> str_replace('http://this-is-a-nice-example/2020.htm', regex('example([/])20'), '' )
[1] "http://this-is-a-nice-20.htm"
```

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Replace with `example20` instead of an empty string

Comment: The answer is at https://stackoverflow.com/a/46112023/3832970

Comment: some redundancy is always good Wiktor :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can wrap with `fixed` instead of trying to escape the metacharacter with `regex`

```
library(stringr)
str_replace(url1, fixed("example/"), "example")
#[1] "http://this-is-a-nice-example2020.htm"
```

Or if we use `regex`,

```
str_replace(url1, regex("example/"), "example")
#[1] "http://this-is-a-nice-example2020.htm"
```

Or using the OP's code, we need the value in the `replacement`

```
str_replace('http://this-is-a-nice-example/2020.htm', regex('example[/]20'), 'example20' )
#[1] "http://this-is-a-nice-example2020.htm"
```

#### data

```
url1 <- "http://this-is-a-nice-example/2020.htm"
```

Comment: thanks, that works but why isnt the regex working?

Comment: @ℕʘʘḆḽḘ i think you can use the `\\` to escape. instead of `[`

Comment: Why escape ``\`` if it is not a special regex metacharacter?